# Redux hooks in regular function (rules-of-hooks)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I'm having a trouble with a regular function. In my component, I'm loading lot of products with a function that is reusable everywhere. So I have a file named products.js where some functions are defined.
In a function called 'getPrice', I need to get a param called 'beautifullPrice' stored in the redux store, on a reducer.

If I do it respecting hooks rules, I have to implement useSelector in my components and pass 'beautifullPrice' as a param in every functions. But my 'getPrice' is a sub sub sub call. So I need to declare 'beautifullPrice' in tons of functions, and this param cant change till the application is not reloaded.

So, in my opinion, the easiest way to do this is to use useSelector directly in my function 'getPrice', all my functions wont have one more params, it will be cleaner. But according to react-rules, I should not do this.

First question : Why this rule ? I tried and it seems to work well.
Second question : Is there an other proper way to do this ?

Am I the only one facing this type of problem ? =D

Thx for reading, and for help !

Comment: Please post code, what have you tried?

Comment: You are writing " I'm loading lot of products with a function that is reusable everywhere." The proper way which follows the rules of hooks is to create your own custom hook - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html. You can use hooks in custom hooks too.

Comment: Ho yea, that's a great idea, I'll try with it ! A custom hook could be a regular function that can handle use of hooks right ? 
Sorry can't post code coz i'm not allowed to

Comment: Yes it is a regular function, it has to follow some rules, check that tutorial for those.